# Custom widths for multiple inputs in Bootstrap input group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I am using Bootstrap and Simple Form.  I have an odd ball form element that I am trying construct.  This is the code that gets me 95% of the way there:

```
    <%= f.input :lsd_from, label: 'LSD From', wrapper: :horizontal_input_group do %>
      <%= f.text_field :lsd_from, placeholder: 'LSD', class: 'form-control' %>
      <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
      <%= f.text_field :sec_from, placeholder: 'SEC', class: 'form-control' %>
      <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
      <%= f.text_field :twp_from, placeholder: 'TWP', class: 'form-control' %>
      <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
      <%= f.text_field :rge_from, placeholder: 'RGE', class: 'form-control' %>
      <span class="input-group-addon">W</span>
      <%= f.text_field :m_from, class: 'form-control' %>
      <span class="input-group-addon">M</span>
    <% end %>
```

which renders to:

```
<div class="form-group integer optional pipeline_segment_lsd_from">
  <label class="integer optional col-sm-2 control-label" for="pipeline_segment_lsd_from">LSD From</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="input-group col-sm-12">
      <input placeholder="LSD" class="form-control" type="text" name="pipeline_segment[lsd_from]" id="pipeline_segment_lsd_from" style="width: 50px;">
      <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
      <input placeholder="SEC" class="form-control" type="text" name="pipeline_segment[sec_from]" id="pipeline_segment_sec_from" style="width: 50px;">
      <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
      <input placeholder="TWP" class="form-control" type="text" name="pipeline_segment[twp_from]" id="pipeline_segment_twp_from" style="width: 50px;">
      <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
      <input placeholder="RGE" class="form-control" type="text" name="pipeline_segment[rge_from]" id="pipeline_segment_rge_from" style="width:  50px;">
      <span class="input-group-addon">W</span>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="pipeline_segment[m_from]" id="pipeline_segment_m_from" style="width:  20px;">
      <span class="input-group-addon">M</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and looks like this:

[image]

I am looking for this:

[image]

The issues are

- The slight spacing between the `input-group-addon` and neighbouring inputs
- How can I set a specific width to the individual fields?

If I try to fix the width of the fields the wrapper span wants to stretch to fill the parent and I end up with all sorts of padding / margins between the elements like this:

[image]

On a side note:

1. I should make the `input-group-addon` a light grey etc.
2. I should also make the placeholder text lighter
3. This data entry is known to the user so the lack of traditional field labels should not be an issue

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution. I hope this will work in your situation.

Please check example at **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/ZpYYxR?editors=1100)**

Instead of setting width to inputs. You can wrap a **div** around the input-group and set the max-width to that **div**, in that way you can have the widths of input fixed, even if you stretch the viewport area.

And also considering your side points i made some changes too. Please check the example link for that.

HTML:

```
<div class="section-input">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input placeholder="LSD" class="form-control" type="text" name="pipeline_segment[lsd_from]" id="pipeline_segment_lsd_from">
        <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
        <input placeholder="SEC" class="form-control" type="text" name="pipeline_segment[sec_from]" id="pipeline_segment_sec_from">
        <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
        <input placeholder="TWP" class="form-control" type="text" name="pipeline_segment[twp_from]" id="pipeline_segment_twp_from">
        <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
        <input placeholder="RGE" class="form-control" type="text" name="pipeline_segment[rge_from]" id="pipeline_segment_rge_from">
        <span class="input-group-addon">W</span>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="pipeline_segment[m_from]" id="pipeline_segment_m_from">
        <span class="input-group-addon">M</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.section-input {
  max-width: 454px;
  margin: auto;
}

.section-input .input-group .form-control {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 1px solid #555;
}

.section-input .input-group .input-group-addon {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.section-input .input-group .input-group-addon:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #555;
}

.section-input .input-group .input-group-addon:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #555;
}
```

Enjoy :)